# Microsoft Graph API which version

Tags: azure, oauth, microsoft-graph-api

When visiting the url - https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

In the graph explorer it has a drop down 1.0 or beta.  Is beta version 2.0 that Microsoft references in all of it's documentation?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/azure-ad-endpoint-comparison

This would be a great question answered because I do not see a drop down for v2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things to differentiate here. Azure active directory is the central identity service behind most of Microsoft SaaS services.
It provides two main things

- a central identity database that stores users, groups and more. It can be accessed via the graph.windows.net API. Although it's recommended to use the Microsoft graph instead now.
- authentication and authorization services. That live mostly under login.microsoftonline.com.

The later provides two versions of the service v1/v2 that implement different capabilities and protocols. (Second documentation link you're providing).

The Microsoft graph on the other hand is the central API for Microsoft 365 services.
The v1 is supported for production workloads, Microsoft is not going to break the API contract and keep the services behind it up and running.
The beta endpoint is where Microsoft makes new things available to get some feedback. Not meant for production workloads. When those new capabilities are ready for prime time, they'll show up under v1.
There's no v2 as of today for the graph. They'll publish a v2 once they need to publish breaking changes to existing capabilities to avoid breaking v1 and disrupting customers.

Comment: Would I be correct in saying if I am using Azure AD as an Identity provider via Microsoft Graph I am using v1?  If (true) {Answer maked as answered};

Comment: The answer to that is complex. Depending on which library you are using (adal or msal) and which capabilities you're leveraging you might be using aad v1 or v2 endpoints for auth purposes. From an API perspective (querying data) you can see which queries the graph is issuing behind the scenes by adding ?$whatif to the end if the URL

Comment: As of for the Microsoft graph, the "version" is always in the URL, so it's easy to know which version of the graph you're using at any time.